Can't get Obfuscar to stop obfuscating a class
I need one of my classes to not be obfuscated, I added all of the SkipNamespace rules and it still doesn't get skipped.
Side note: I had to turn a lot of general rules off so my application doesn't get broken by obfuscation. Most of the rules shown as false below will break my app if turned on.
Side note: any obfuscator recommendations (free/cheap). Would be nice to find one that "just works" with minimal options. Requirements: 1) obfuscates, 2) lets me exclude one class, 3) program still works
I will change the full paths to relative later (once I determine where it runs from):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />

<Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
<Var name="RenameProperties" value="false" />
<Var name="RenameEvents" value="false" />
<Var name="RenameFields" value="false" />
<Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="false" />
<Var name="HideStrings" value="false" />
<Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="false" />
<Var name="SuppressIldasm" value="false" />

<Module file="C:\Users\gerry\Documents\myproject\ProjectFolder\bin\x64\Release\net8.0-windows7.0\MyDll.dll">
    <SkipNamespace name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" />

    <SkipNamespace name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone*" />

    <SkipField type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" attrib="public" name="name" />
    <SkipField type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" attrib="public" rx="Pub.*" />

    <SkipMethod type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" attrib="public" rx=".*" />
    <SkipMethod type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" attrib="family" rx=".*" />

    <SkipType name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" skipMethods="true" />
    <SkipType name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" skipFields="true" />
    <SkipType name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" skipProperties="true" />
    <SkipType name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" skipEvents="true" />
    <SkipType name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" skipMethods="true" skipFields="true" />
    <SkipType name="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" skipStringHiding="true" />

    <SkipProperty type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" name="name" />
    <SkipProperty type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" attrib="public" rx="name\d" />

    <SkipProperty type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" name="Event2" />
    <SkipProperty type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" rx="Any.*" />

    <SkipStringHiding type="MyNamespace.LeaveThisClassAlone" name="*" />
</Module>

<assembly name='$(MSBuildProjectName)' frameworkversion='v4.0' />
<Module file="$(InPath)\MyDll.dll" />
<referencepath path='C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319' />
<AssemblySearchPath path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" />


Hum, nevermind. Cannot find the class I want to hide in ILSpy, yet serialization has started working. I'm using CsvReader which wasn't working but after adding all the skip rules above now it works. Not sure how, but okay.
Anyway, the above obfuscates and my program still runs, so I will leave it here as an example for others. Personally I very much prefer to learn by example.

I also have a working Obfuscar.config for WPF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Obfuscator>
    <Var name="InPath"  value="C:\Users\gerry\Documents\BitBucket\hardmail\bin\x64\Release\net8.0-windows10.0.17763.0" />
    <Var name="OutPath" value="C:\Users\gerry\Documents\BitBucket\hardmail\Obfuscar" />

    <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />

    <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
    <Var name="RenameProperties" value="false" />
    <Var name="RenameEvents" value="false" />
    <Var name="RenameFields" value="false" />
    <Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="false" />
    <Var name="HideStrings" value="false" />
    <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="false" />
    <Var name="SuppressIldasm" value="false" />

    <referencepath      path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF" />
    <referencepath      path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" />
    <AssemblySearchPath path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF" />
    <AssemblySearchPath path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" />

    <Module file="./HardMail.dll" />
</Obfuscator> 

Don't forget for your project file:
   <Target Name="Obfuscate" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="Obfuscar.Console.exe Obfuscar.config" />
  </Target>

Hopefully I can get my project running again (not so far). Also no matter how many times I try and fix InPath Obfuscator cannot find the dll, which is why I just stopped using InPath. OutPath is fine.
To anyone who thinks about becoming a programmer I tell them "no don't do it!"
